# Mails copying instead of moving to local pst in Outlook 2010 with exchange account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have an exchange account , and configured in Outlook 2010 . 
I have created a local pst and configured to move the mails from the exchange mail box to local pst. But the mails are getting copied to local pst multiple times , i.e when a send recieve operation works it copies all the mails every time.

Comment: Is this a domain-controlled business environment? Do you know if policies are controlling how this operation works?

Comment: Yes this is domain controlled , there might be policies

Comment: Then the first thing you should do is ask your local IT. They'll know the applicable policies, and they'll likely be able to assist with solving your problem as well.

Comment: Isn't this involved with any settings in Outlook ?

Comment: First, I'm having difficulty understanding the problem you're describing. Editing your question to make it more clear would be helpful. BUT... even if there are local settings controlling this if there were domain policies they would supersede any local settings you make. Is there any particular reason you do not wish to speak with your local IT about this?

Comment: I wanted to check if this can be resolved by local outlook settings , I have described my question , let me know if you don't get it

Comment: So, each time your Outlook client sends/receives to/from the Exchange server, it downloads new copies of each message? You do know that Exchange servers by default keep copies of all of the messages, that the Exchange/Outlook system together is supposed to allow you to be able to view ALL of your email from any device connected to the server? Depending on how you set up Outlook, you're probably trying to download ALL of the messages EACH time you send/receive. Is there a reason you're doing this rather than abiding by the standard method defined by your local IT?

Comment: Yes each time outlook client is downloading new copies , previously I was downloading the mails with removing it from the exchange mail, but now it copies

Comment: How is the account set up in Outlook? Is it actually an Exchange connection, or POP3, or IMAP?

Comment: Exchange connection

Comment: Then I need to ask once again: Why haven't you asked your local IT about this. Are you hiding something from them? Your lack of response on this specific topic is making me suspicious. This setting can be defined on the Exchange server, and if so, nothing you do will change that fact. You MUST talk with your local IT about this

Comment: There isnt anything suspicious , I just wanted to resolve by myself if possible with local settings , also my IT aren't available now I'll have to talk to them tomorrow , any how let me talk to them , thanks for your help